# SplitLinkedList how to split

Tags: c, list

Sorry, because I am currently working on LinkedList and I got a lot of question for it.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct _listnode
{
    int item;
    struct _listnode *next;
} ListNode;

void split(ListNode *head,ListNode **ptrEvenList,ListNode **ptrOddList);
void printList(ListNode *head);

int main()
{
    ListNode *head = NULL, *temp = NULL;
    ListNode *ptrEvenList = NULL, *ptrOddList = NULL;
    int i = 0;
    int index = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Enter a integer: ");
        scanf("%d", &i);
        if (i == -1)
            break;
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = head;
        }
        else
        {
            temp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
            temp = temp->next;
            temp->next = NULL;
        }
        temp->item = i;
    }
    printList(head);
    split(head,&ptrEvenList, &ptrOddList);
    return 0;
}

void printList(ListNode *head)
{
    int i = 0;
    if (head == NULL)
        return;
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("%d ", head->item);
        head = head->next;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
void split(ListNode *head, ListNode **ptrEvenList, ListNode **ptrOddList)
{
    ListNode *evenTemp =NULL, *oddTemp=NULL;
    while (head->next != NULL)
    {

        if (head->item % 2 == 0)
        {
            if (ptrEvenList == NULL)
            {
                ptrEvenList = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                evenTemp = ptrEvenList;
            }
            else
            {
                evenTemp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                evenTemp = evenTemp->next;
                evenTemp->next = NULL;
            }
            evenTemp->item = head->item;
        }
        if (head->item % 2 != 0)
        {
            if (ptrOddList == NULL)
            {
                ptrOddList = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                oddTemp = ptrOddList;
            }
            else
            {
                oddTemp->next = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
                oddTemp = oddTemp->next;
                oddTemp->next = NULL;
            }
            oddTemp->item = head->item;
        }
        head = head->next;
    }
    printList(ptrEvenList);
    printList(ptrOddList);
}
```

I am trying to split my linked list by OddList and EvenList from the integer. But I am not sure which part I went wrong. It seems to have error on the split function. After the printList, my program auto terminate.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: you passing ListNode** in printList from the end of split function, could that be one of the causes of problem?

Comment: You also want to leave the original list intact (since you appear to be cloning all the nodes) ? BTW: `oddTemp = oddTemp->next;
                oddTemp->next = NULL;` -->>`oddTemp->next = NULL; oddTemp = oddTemp->next;
                `

Comment: yes i want to keep the original list intact.

Answer (score 0):

Problems seen so far:
1) You will miss the last node, and should do this instead:

```
while (head != null)
```

2) (this will be your main problem, I should think) you don't initialize the `next` pointer when you create your first element. Use `calloc` or set `next = null;`

---

Edit:
Best thing to do is: **debug it**!

The debugger will show you which line is causing the termination. It's not necessarily the line with the problem in: it's quite likely you're referencing invalid memory via an uninitialised pointer (e.g. like my 2nd point above) - but in the debugger all will be revealed and you'll home-in on the problem. Good luck!

Comment: theres an error in the split function, my program terminates straight

Comment: Debug it. Then you'll know which line is causing the problem. I'll update my answer with info on what to look for ...

Answer (score 0):

```
void split(ListNode *head, ListNode **even, ListNode **odd)
{
    ListNode** lists[2] = {even, odd};
    for(;head;head = head->next) { /* loop over all elements */
        ListNode*** target = &lists[head->item&1];
        **target = malloc(sizeof ***target);
        ***target = (ListNode){head->item};
        *target = &((**target)->next);
    }
    printList(*even);
    printList(*odd);
}
```

That should do your split...

BTW: This is known disparagingly as three-star-programming.

Comment: You seem to get lost in the stars ;-). Take care how many indirections you need at each step...

Comment: And you forgot to set evenTemp/oddTemp ->next to 0, if ptr(even|odd)list was 0 before. Same in main().

Answer (score 0):

```
void split(ListNode *org, ListNode **ptrEvenList, ListNode **ptrOddList)
{
    for(    ;org; org = org->next) {
        ListNode *new;

        new = malloc(sizeof *new);
        new->item = org->item;
        new->next = NULL;

        if (new->item % 2) {
                *ptrOddList = new;
                ptrOddList = &new->next;
                }
        else    {
                *ptrEvenList = new;
                ptrEvenList = &new->next;
                }
    }
}
```

Comment: It si basically the same as the code from @Deduplicator, but without the three stars (and without the indirection errors and the axcess parentheses). You can easily verify that per iteration of the loop exactly one node is created, and that it is appended to eiter the odd chain or the even chain.

Comment: i tried to run the code, but it didnt work as well. there seem to be an error on new->item = org->item. the debugger stop there as well

Comment: I can see no errors (except for possible malloc() failure, which I did not handle, for breviy)

Comment: @wildplasser: Where did i have indirection errors? Or too many parentheses?

Comment: `***target = (ListNode){head->item};` Resolves to a node. (which _is_ a assignable lvalue, but not of type int) The `*target = &((**target)->next);` has an unneeded pair of parentheses ( `->` binds tighter than `&` ), which is harmless.

Comment: Well, the one (and only) unneeded parentheses i will concede. the other one does not make sense. `***target` and `(ListNode){head->item}` are both of type `ListNode`, lvalue and compound literal respectively, so all is well...